# Проблема с версиями node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

При настройке сервера `ubuntu 16.04` установил `Node.js` через `nvm`. Установил `v.8.0.0` при запуске сервера вылетает ошибка, понял что суть в версии `Node.js`. 
Вот что выдает терминал:

```js
aloha@infopanda:~/infopanda.ru$ nodejs -v
v4.2.6
```

```js
aloha@infopanda:~/infopanda.ru$ node -v
v8.0.0
```

Как сделать так, чтобы использовался только `node` (а не `nodejs`), так как все остальное (nodemon и pm2) используют именно команду `node`?

Comment: удалите всё и установите по инструкции - https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions Для запуска разных версий node.js используйте Docker, нет смысла в nvm

Comment: Не слушайте совет про Docker. Не нужно это дело пихать куда ни попадя.

Comment: @Suvitruf оффтоп https://twitter.com/search_adm/status/1026194090701058050?s=21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, одно время я действительно пользовался nvm и мне было удобно. 
недавно я был вынужден переехать на другую машину и снова полез искать как установить node.js на ubuntu

Описываю 2 самых простых способа:

Для начала установим необходимые пакеты

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev`

1. Установка node.js с долгосрочной поддержкой, на данный момент это 8.0.0
   Все до смешного просто:

`sudo apt install nodejs`

При необходимости `npm` ставится так же

`sudo apt install npm`

2. Если Вам нужна какая-то определенная версия

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh`

При этом вместо '8' в слове 'setup_8.x' заменяем на ту версию, которая Вам нужна.
Далее выполним только что скачанный скрипт из репозиториев Node

`sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh`

И собственно устанавливаем node.js с параметром `-y`

`sudo apt install -y nodejs`

Вуаля, у вас нужная Вам версия node.js и npm.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно `nvm` (или `n`) был полезен "раньше". Сейчас есть две основных версии Node - текущая (current) и LTS. Они стабильны и нет никакой причины гибко настраивать версии, кроме как поддержка `legacy` приложений. Но и тут Docker будет намного удобней. Используйте [официальную инструкцию](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

А для запуска разных версий [Docker/Node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)

```
docker run --rm -it node:carbon ...
```

Рекомендую не использовать `nvm`, `n` и официальные версии из репозиториев Ubuntu. **А использовать Docker для разных версий, и LTS версию Node.js как основной пакет. Это очень стабильная связка и в разработке и в production.**

Comment: Благодарю, к сожалению с Docker еще не работал, но уже качаю и ищу мануалы. Просто сроки горят, надо сегодня кровь из носа запустить демку((

Comment: удалите оригинальный `apt-get purge nodejs` (!!! если он вам не нужен) и переустановите nvm.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в системе просто две версии nodejs установлено. Удалите одну.

Посмотрите, где они у вас лежат:

```
whereis node
whereis nodejs
```

Я бы рекомендовал удалить оба, а потом переустановить.

Ну или симлинк сделайте.

Comment: А кого на кого ссылать?

Comment: Я бы nodejs  на node сделал.